# Upload PDF to Google site

Tags: google, pdf, google-sites, file-upload

I have created a Google site with my custom domain (`www.example.com`)

How I can add a PDF file without having to uploaded to Google drive. I want to have a link with my PDF like: `www.example.com/file.pdf`. Because I am forced to open a drive link using the a smartphone. I don't want to open the drive link.

It is possible?

Comment: Google sites is missing a lot of functionality. They try to make it easy to use rather than giving site creators lots of options.  It wouldn't surprise me if there is no way to upload PDF files to your site.

Comment: I can upload it, but first I have to upload it to Drive and the user can only open it with the Drive link.